# How to control the z axis of individual Mapbox features inside the same layer?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm using the Mapbox Maps SDK for Android to display pins with custom icons in a map on my app. More specifically, I'm using the SymbolLayer API. When the user clicks on a pin, its appearance changes to show it is selected. However, that clicked pin is often behind other pins, like in this image:
[image]

All those pins are `Feature`s from the same `Source`, added to the same `SymbolLayer`.

I want to be able to make the selected pin appear above the other pins, and for that I'm trying to control its z axis. I'm playing around with the `PropertyFactory.symbolZOrder(value)` method and it seems that neither `Property.SYMBOL_Z_ORDER_VIEWPORT_Y` nor `Property.SYMBOL_Z_ORDER_SOURCE` will be of help. I'm hopeful that I will be able to achieve that with an `Expression` but I have no idea on how to use it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `SYMBOL_Z_ORDER_SOURCE ` will allow you to specific the order of the z index of symbols. What you need to to do is order the contents of the your source object and this will be taken in account when laying out all the symbols. I created a high level api around symbols that uses the `SYMBOL_Z_ORDER_SOURCE ` feature for this specific reason. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/commit/8f133ad5c83ae8b758648848e57015808748f92d

Comment: @Tobrun do you have an example of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's an example with explanations.
You should set the properties `symbolZOrder` and `symbolSortKey` when defining the symbol layer.

`symbolZOrder` accept one of the following as argument:

```
  // SYMBOL_Z_ORDER: Controls the order in which overlapping symbols in the same layer are rendered

  /**
   * If symbol sort key is set, sort based on that. Otherwise sort symbols by their y-position relative to the viewport.
   */
  public static final String SYMBOL_Z_ORDER_AUTO = "auto";
  /**
   * Symbols will be sorted by their y-position relative to the viewport.
   */
  public static final String SYMBOL_Z_ORDER_VIEWPORT_Y = "viewport-y";
  /**
   * Symbols will be rendered in the same order as the source data with no sorting applied.
   */
  public static final String SYMBOL_Z_ORDER_SOURCE = "source";
```

so if you wish to control the symbols based on some logic you should use the `SYMBOL_Z_ORDER_AUTO`  value.

then you can set the `symbolSortKey` to some float value.

```
        Style.OnStyleLoaded onStyleLoaded = style -> {
            style.addLayer(new SymbolLayer(SYMBOLS_LAYER, SYMBOLS_SOURCE)
                    .withProperties(
                            iconImage(step(zoom(),
                                    literal("marker_public_base"),
                                    stop(6, get("icon")))),
                            iconIgnorePlacement(true),
                            iconAllowOverlap(true),
                            iconSize(interpolate(
                                    linear(), zoom(),
                                    stop(0, MARKER_SYMBOL_SIZE * .13),
                                    stop(5, MARKER_SYMBOL_SIZE * .33),
                                    stop(9, MARKER_SYMBOL_SIZE))),
                            iconAnchor(ICON_ANCHOR_BOTTOM),
                            textField(get("title")),
                            textSize(interpolate(
                                    linear(), zoom(),
                                    stop(5.9, 0),
                                    stop(6, SYMBOL_TEXT_SIZE * .4),
                                    stop(7, SYMBOL_TEXT_SIZE * .7),
                                    stop(11, SYMBOL_TEXT_SIZE))),
                            textOptional(true),
                            textHaloColor("#ffffff"),
                            textHaloWidth(1f),
                            textHaloBlur(1f),
                            textAnchor(TEXT_ANCHOR_TOP),
                            symbolZOrder(SYMBOL_Z_ORDER_AUTO),
                            symbolSortKey(get("zIndex"))
                    ));
```

where

```
            points.forEach(point -> {
                Feature feature = Feature.fromGeometry(com.mapbox.geojson.Point.fromLngLat(point.lon, point.lat));
                feature.addStringProperty("id", point.id);
                feature.addNumberProperty("zIndex", point.isPublic? 0f :  point.isSearchResult? 2f : 1f);
                feature.addStringProperty("title", point.name);
                feature.addStringProperty("icon", getIconImageID(point.category, point.isPublic, point.visited));

                symbolsFeatures.add(feature);
            });
```